# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value ....)

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

I'm making an android application in eclipse, and I want to upload it to the Google Play store. How ever, the store says that I need to add an Icon to it. I programmed the icon, but it gives the following error:

```
error: Error: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher')`.
```

I have no idea how to fix it, the image is in my drawable-hdpi folder and is spelled correctly and everything.

Can someone help me out?

This is my AndoidManifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rodekruis"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:icon="@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAINACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BezoekActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bezoek" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BEZOEKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AfspraakActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_afspraak" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AFSPRAAKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.CONTACTACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MeningActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mening" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MENINGACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RouteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_route" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.ROUTEACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SpecialistenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_specialisten" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.SPECIALISTENACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BWCActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bwc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BWCACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AgendaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AGENDAACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_informatie" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.INFOACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VriendActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vriend" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.VRIENDACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FoldersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_folders" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.FOLDERSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NieuwsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuws">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.NIEUWSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` in the applicaiton node. The system will automatically choose the right drawable folder (hdpi, xhdpi, ...) according to the pixel density of the device which run the application.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Another thing, I'm able to run my project now, but the store still tells me that I have to add an icon to my project. Do you know why, or how i fix that?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the whole message ?

Comment: I've added the picture to my post. It says in english: You have to add an icon to your APK. Upload another APK

Comment: Check if your app icon (ic_launcher) is declined in all (five) pixel densities (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, ...). And use mipmap folders instead of drawable folder for app icons.

Comment: I did that. Another question, I'm sorry i'm not too good at this. In my files, under my project where my apk is showed, which I add in to the google play store, it says "last changed" with a date. When i change my project and save it, the date doesn't of my apk change. Does that have to do with it, and do you know why that doesn't change?

Comment: I advice you to post a new question with associated tags.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 android:icon="@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher"
```

to

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Another thing, I'm able to run my project now, but the store still tells me that I have to add an icon to my project. Do you know why, or how i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

mistake is in the below line

```
 android:icon="@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher"
```

instead use

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

it will automatically pick up its best

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Another thing, I'm able to run my project now, but the store still tells me that I have to add an icon to my project. Do you know why, or how i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below snippet

```
android:icon="@drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher"
```

to

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Another thing, I'm able to run my project now, but the store still tells me that I have to add an icon to my project. Do you know why, or how i fix that?

Comment: Can you show a sample screenshot of the error you are getting?

Comment: I've added the picture to my post. It says in english: You have to add an icon to your APK. Upload another APK

Comment: Can you create folders in mipmap format and change the reference like this android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher". Updated my comment with screenshot

Comment: So just change all the folder names from drawable to mipmap, and then also change that in my code? Or create new folders with those names?

Comment: Create new folders with that name and  just copy only the launcher icons to the new folders

Comment: Just the hdpi is neccesary right? cause there is nothing in mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. Or do I need to make those as well?

Comment: Never mind that was a dumb question. I did that. Another question, I'm sorry i'm not too good at this. In my files, under my project where my apk is showed, which I add in to the google play store, it says "last changed" with a date. When i change my project and save it, the date doesn't of my apk change. Does that have to do with it, and do you know why that doesn't change?

Comment: Are you saying about the developer console or from the IDE perspective?